# How to make autogeneration of buttons in a form by getting labels and button names from database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, ms-access

I want to make autogeneration of buttons in a form by getting labels and button names from database.
I'm coding in C# Visual Studio 2013.WinForms.
Tip of direction of how get label names and code it in C# is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you save the names of the textboxes and labels into lists

```
List<string> labels = new List<string>();
List<string> textboxes = new List<string>();
```

Then you just itterate through them, create the controls and put them on your form like this:

```
    for(int a = 0; a< label.count;a++){

    Label l = new Label();
    l.Location = new Point(5,5+a*20);
    l.Text = label[a];
    this.Controls.Add(l);
}

for(int a = 0; a< textboxes.count;a++){

    TextBox t = new TextBox();
    tl.Location = new Point(100,5+a*20);
    t.Text = textboxes[a];
    this.Controls.Add(t);
}
```